# Merge [robots] and [robotics]

Tags: support, retag-request

Can we please merge the [robots](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robots) and [robotics](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotics) tags? We don't need both of them.

I think that [robotics](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotics) is the better tag, because it fits better with the theme of the site - we don't want people asking random robot questions here.